# Adding a Column into a Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

As a new guy with VBA, I haven't explored the full extent of Pivot Tables, using VBA...Also, as someone who just began using Pivot Tables, I also do not know the full extent of Pivot Tables (without VBA)....so the answer to this question could be either by using VBA, or perhaps I've missed something, and excel allows you to do what I need to do.

I have a pivot table with fields like, "Client" as row labels, with summing of revenue in the end.

In my data set, i have a column labeled "Currency" (USD, EUR, GBP etc.)...can i use this pivot table to display both the client names, AND what their currency is, without making the currency a seperate filter (where it shows every available currency).

Essentially I want it to look like this:

```
Clinet    Currency        Total


The Beatles  Eur          6723
Rush         CAD          23023
RHCP         USD          5230
```

Instead of

```
Client     EUR    USD   CAD     
The Beatles 6723 
 RHCP             5230
 Rush                   23023
```

You may be asking why not just use the table, and no pivot at all...mainly because I'm going to be filtering out by other fields not listed...and the ability to Sum by date, and stuff.

Comment: Why not just drag the currency to the "Row Labels", and then disable the subtotals for the "Client" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Currency needs to be a Row field (drag Currency from Column Labels to
  Row Labels)
- You also need to use the "Classic" PivotTable layout (right-click the
  pivot table, select PivotTable Options, Display tab, check Classic
  layout),
- And you need to turn off subtotals (right-click one of the client
  names, uncheck Subtotals, same with a currency).

Comment: thank you,....I knew there HAD to be a way of doing it...just not immediately obvious (and a tough google search to get what I needed).

Answer (score 0):

As stated by MP24, this is a very simple matter of making the currency a row field. In order to do that, click on the pivot table and the pivot fields should appear in the menu on the right of the window. Drag the currency field from the column fields to the row fields and it should do the job.